# How to take checked radio buttons on a user input form in Android and store the selections as a String

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a very simple Android application (using Java) that will take user input. It has several input fields with EditTexts and Radiobuttons and a submit Button. I am not sure if I am implementing the Radiobuttons correctly.

The app compiles and runs okay, when the activity opens I can input values etc. but nothing happens when selecting the Submit button. I have tried debugging but as the app does not crash it has hard to know what is the issue.

N.B. my API, PHP scripts and database etc is working; I have working sign up / sign in activities and the POST method for my user input form is working as I have tested with Postman

public class IncidentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText editTextStreet, editTextTown, editTextDetails;

private RadioButton btnGenUnknown, btnGenMale, btnGenFemale, btnBedUnknown, btnBedYes, btnBedNo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incident);

    editTextStreet = findViewById(R.id.editTextStreet);
    editTextTown = findViewById(R.id.editTextTown);

    btnGenUnknown = findViewById(R.id.btnGenUnknown);
    btnGenMale = findViewById(R.id.btnGenMale);
    btnGenFemale = findViewById(R.id.btnGenFemale);
    btnBedUnknown = findViewById(R.id.btnBedUnknown);
    btnBedYes = findViewById(R.id.btnBedYes);
    btnBedNo = findViewById(R.id.btnBedNo);

    editTextDetails = findViewById(R.id.editTextDetails);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            logIncident();
        }
    });

}

private void logIncident() {

    String street = editTextStreet.getText().toString().trim();
    String town = editTextTown.getText().toString().trim();
    String details = editTextDetails.getText().toString().trim();
    String gender;
    String bedded;

    if (!btnGenUnknown.isChecked()) {
        if (!btnGenMale.isChecked()){
            btnGenFemale.setText("Female");
            gender = btnGenFemale.toString();
        }
        else{
            btnGenMale.setText("Male");
            gender = btnGenMale.toString();
        }
    }else{
        btnGenUnknown.setText("Unknown");
        gender = btnGenUnknown.toString();
    }

    if (!btnBedUnknown.isChecked()) {
        if (!btnBedYes.isChecked()){
            btnBedNo.setText("No");
            bedded = btnBedNo.toString();
        }
        else{
            btnBedYes.setText("Yes");
            bedded = btnBedYes.toString();
        }
    }else{
        btnBedUnknown.setText("Unknown");
        bedded = btnBedUnknown.toString();
    }

    /* Logging incident using the API call */
    Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .logIncident(street, town, gender, bedded, details);

    /* Executing the HTTP call */
    call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {

            if(response.code() == 201){

                DefaultResponse dr = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(IncidentActivity.this, dr.getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(IncidentActivity.this, "Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

On hitting the submit button the values should be stored as Strings and posted to my database

[Activity layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VZ3L.png)

Comment: Why are you binding your button on the button click itself? that make no sense, try to take this line `findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);` and put it in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Like Amine has said, your usage of the button doesn't make since. You should set a Button Object equal to findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit) and then set the onclicklistener for that button.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain what are btnGenUnknown and btnBedUnknown (I think they are RadioButtons, but we don't know RadioGroups), then explain what is returned from btnGedUnknown.toString() and what do you want to assign to variables gender and bedded; also consider the 2 comments above, they are right

Comment: Thank you Amine and ck1221, I have amended the onClick method. I have added an image of the activity layout which I should clarify what the RadioButtons are and what they should return. The default value for both is 'Unknown', but if the user selects Male/Female, Yes/No then the String variable 'gender' should = Male or Female and the String variable 'bedded' should = Yes or No. I hope this helps explain what I am trying to do and thank you guys for looking at my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create an object for button
      Button button = findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //Call your method from here
                            logIncident();
           }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks Triyambak, I have tried your suggestion but still having the same issue. After improving the Radio Buttons code I am now wondering if the issue is with my HTTP call and call.enqueue() method :-/